# How do I make the code inside the 2nd if statement, which is inside a foreach loop, run only once?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this foreach loop to iterate through the controls in my form, so I can find the picturebox that I am moving with the arrow keys and checking if it collides with other pictureboxes via tags. I now want to check if the picturebox collides with a picturebox with the tag "portal", and if so, it has to open a new form and close/hide the current one, which I did and works fine. The only problem I have is that it opens the second form 13 times, and I think it's because it runs the foreach loop for 13 times and runs those 3 lines of code 13 times, but I want them to run only once, open the new form and close/hide the current one just once.

```
private void moveTimerEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (moveLeft == true && pictureBox1.Left > 10)
            {
                pictureBox1.Left -= speed;
            }
            if (moveRight == true && pictureBox1.Left < 1850) //right border of the screen.
            {
                pictureBox1.Left += speed;
            }
            if (moveUp == true && pictureBox1.Top > 10)
            {
                pictureBox1.Top -= speed;
            }
            if (moveDown == true && pictureBox1.Top < 962) //bottom border of the screen.
            {
                pictureBox1.Top += speed;
            }
            foreach (Control x in this.Controls) //foreach loop that I am referring to
            {
                if (x is PictureBox && (string)x.Tag == "wall")
                {
                    if (pictureBox1.Bounds.IntersectsWith(x.Bounds))
                    {
                        pictureBox1.Location = new Point(123, 962);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (x is PictureBox && (string)x.Tag == "portal") //if statement that I am also referring to
                    {
                        if (pictureBox1.Bounds.IntersectsWith(x.Bounds)) //if statement that runs 13 times, but only has to run once
                        {
                            Form2 f2 = new Form2(); //open form2
                            f2.Show(); //show it
                            this.Hide(); //close this one
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I tried adding a break after the code I want to run only once, but it still opened the new form 13 times. I was expecting the break to run it once and stop running those lines.

Comment: Where exactly did you put the `break;`?

Comment: straight after the this.Hide();

Comment: Maybe your `moveTimerEvent` is called multiple times?

Comment: The moveTimerEvent has an interval of 20, because it checks for the keyup and keydown states to move the picturebox through the form

Comment: You should probably stop the timer then

Answer (score 0):

Your post describes some problems you're having with the timer scheme and inner loop that you show in your code. But what is your actual objective? You state in the post that its *raison d'etre* is:

> [...] so I can find the picturebox that I am moving with the arrow keys and checking if it collides with other pictureboxes via tags.

This "might" be considered an [X-Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)
because there may be a more optimal way than a timer to achieve what you wanted to do in the first place (because a timer with a 20ms interval might present some race conditions that make it hard to start and stop predictably). Here's one alternative:

---

**ArrowKeyPictureBox**

Consider customizing `PictureBox` that can `MoveProgrammatically(Keys direction)` when Left, Right, Up or Down is pressed. It would also need to keep track of whether this *particular* picture box is the one that's supposed to move, based on its `IsCurrentMoveTarget` property. And when it *does* become the current move target, it notifies all the *other* instances that they no longer are.

[image: screenshot]

```
class ArrowKeyPictureBox : PictureBox
{
    public ArrowKeyPictureBox() 
    {
        LostFocus += (sender, e) =>Refresh();
        GotFocus += (sender, e) =>Refresh();
        MouseDown += (sender, e) =>
        {
            Focus();
            foreach (var control in Parent.Controls.OfType<ArrowKeyPictureBox>())
            {
                if (!ReferenceEquals(control, this)) control.IsCurrentMoveTarget = false;
            }
            IsCurrentMoveTarget = true;
        };
        Paint += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (Focused && IsCurrentMoveTarget) using (var pen = new Pen(Color.Fuchsia))
                {
                    var rect = new Rectangle(
                        e.ClipRectangle.Location,
                        new Size(
                            (int)(e.ClipRectangle.Width - pen.Width),
                            (int)(e.ClipRectangle.Height - pen.Width)));
                    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);
                }
        };
    }
```

Move method has collision detection and fires a cancellable event when imminent.

```
    const int INCREMENT = 1;
    public void MoveProgrammatically(Keys direction)
    {
        Rectangle preview = Bounds;
        if (IsCurrentMoveTarget)
        {
            BringToFront();
            switch (direction)
            {
                case Keys.Up:
                    if (Top <= 0)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    preview.Y -= INCREMENT;
                    if(detectCollision())
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    Top = preview.Y;
                    break;
                case Keys.Down:
                    if (Bottom >= Parent.Bottom)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    preview.Y += INCREMENT;
                    if (detectCollision())
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    Top = preview.Y;
                    break;
                case Keys.Left:
                    if (Left <= 0)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    preview.X -= INCREMENT;
                    if (detectCollision())
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    Left = preview.X;
                    break;
                case Keys.Right:
                    if (Right >= Parent.Right)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    preview.X += INCREMENT;
                    if (detectCollision())
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    Left = preview.X;
                    break;
            }
        }
        bool detectCollision()
        {
            foreach (Control control in Parent.Controls)
            {
                if(!ReferenceEquals(this, control))
                {
                    if(preview.IntersectsWith(control.Bounds))
                    {
                        var e = new CollisionDetectedEventArgs(control: control);
                        CollisionDetected?.Invoke(this, e);
                        return !e.Cancel;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
    public static event CollisionDetectedEventHandler CollisionDetected;
```

Determines whether this is the control to move, and whether to draw the focus rectangle.

```
    public bool IsCurrentMoveTarget
    {
        get => _isCurrentMoveTarget;
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_isCurrentMoveTarget, value))
            {
                _isCurrentMoveTarget = value;
                Refresh();
            }
        }
    }
    bool _isCurrentMoveTarget = false;
}
```

---

**Main Form**

The main form employs a [MessageFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.addmessagefilter) for Up Down Left Right key events and broadcasts any occurrence to all of the `ArrowKeyPictureBox` instances it might hold.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form , IMessageFilter
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Application.AddMessageFilter(this);
        Disposed += (sender, e) => Application.RemoveMessageFilter(this);
        ArrowKeyPictureBox.CollisionDetected += onAnyCollisionDetected;
    }

    const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case WM_KEYDOWN:
                if (Controls.OfType<ArrowKeyPictureBox>().Any(_ => _.Focused))
                {
                    Keys key = (Keys)m.WParam;
                    switch (key)
                    {
                        case Keys.Up:
                        case Keys.Down:
                        case Keys.Left:
                        case Keys.Right:
                            BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                            {
                                foreach (var target in Controls.OfType<ArrowKeyPictureBox>())
                                {
                                    target.MoveProgrammatically(key);
                                }
                            }));
                            // Suppress OS tabbing to prevent loss of focus.
                            return true;
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Display collision status:

```
    private void onAnyCollisionDetected(object sender, CollisionDetectedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = !e.Control.Name.Contains("Portal");
        if (sender is Control control)
        {
            if (!_prevWarning.Equals(control.Bounds))
            {
                richTextBox.SelectionFont = new Font(richTextBox.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
                richTextBox.SelectionColor = e.Cancel ? Color.Green : Color.Red;
                richTextBox.AppendText($"{Environment.NewLine}Collision{Environment.NewLine}");
                richTextBox.SelectionFont = new Font(richTextBox.Font, FontStyle.Regular);
                richTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.Black;

                List<string> builder = new List<string>();
                builder.Add($"Moving: {control.Name}");
                builder.Add($"@ {control.Bounds}");
                builder.Add($"Collided with: {e.Control.Name}");
                builder.Add($"@ {e.Control.Bounds}");
                richTextBox.AppendText($"{string.Join(Environment.NewLine, builder)}{Environment.NewLine}");
                richTextBox.ScrollToCaret();
                _prevWarning = control.Bounds;
            }
        }
    }
    Rectangle _prevWarning = new Rectangle();
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to swap out instances of `PictureBox` with `ArrowKeyPictureBox` in the main form's designer file. [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/move-picture-box-with-arrow-keys.git) demo code for example.